# Problem with Tkinter on Raspberry with fswebcam

Tags: exception, tkinter, operating-system, raspbian, webcam

I was making a simple project with Tkinter on a Raspberry board, the program show a window and a button.
The instruction "os.system('fswebcam -r 640x360 --no-banner img_begin.png')" allow me to take a picture from webcam, I tested it in another program and it work correctly.
When the button is pressed, a picture is taken then, this picture it's showed inside of the window.
Here's the code:

```
BARCODE = Tk()

BARCODE.attributes('-zoomed', True )

BARCODE.configure(bg='#341C41')     

tf_BC = Frame(BARCODE, bg='#341C41', width=50, height=80, pady=3)
center_BC = Frame(BARCODE, bg='#341C41', width=50, height=40, padx=3, pady=3)
btm_BC = Frame(BARCODE, bg='#341C41', width=450, height=45, pady=3)

# layout 
BARCODE.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
BARCODE.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

tf_BC.grid(row=0, sticky="ew")
center_BC.grid(row=1, sticky="nsew")
btm_BC.grid(row=3, sticky="ew")

ph_uploadph = PhotoImage(file="howtophoto.png")
lb_upload = Label(center_BC, image=ph_uploadph)
lb_upload.pack()

bt_photoimg = Button (center_BC , text = "Photo", bg='green', fg ="white", font = ("Times",25)  )
bt_photoimg.pack( pady=10)


def display_photo():

    os.system( 'fswebcam -r 640x360 --no-banner img_begin.png' )
    #time.sleep(0.500)
    ph_displayph = PhotoImage(file="img_begin.png")
    lb_upload.config( image = ph_displayph )
    lb_upload.image = ph_displayph    


bt_photoimg.configure( command = lambda: display_photo() )
BARCODE.mainloop()
```

And this is the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1562, in call
return self.func(*args)
File "/home/pi/Downloads/barcode cardreader.py", line 101, in <lambda>
bt_photoimg.configure( command = lambda: display_photo() )
File "/home/pi/Downloads/barcode cardreader.py", line 55, in display_photo
ph_displayph = PhotoImage(file="img_begin.png")
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3406, in init
Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3362, in init
self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "img_begin.png"
```

Comment: You're using python 3.5. Tkinter in that version doesn't support png format.

Comment: png don't give any problem, the first photo is loaded correctly on the window, the exception is triggered when I press the button

Comment: Then the error means precisely what it says - even though the file is named `img_begin.png`, tkinter doesn't recoginize it as a png file. Have you examined the file generated by  your python script to make sure it is a valid png file?

Comment: img_begin.png open correctly, can it be some problem linked with os.system command? Does the program wait until the end of the command or it go on with execution?